# How to specify which project to get the path of the Excel file from?

Tags: c#, excel, reflection

Currently in my solution I have 3 projects. I want to keep only one Excel file in one of them, and read from it in the other two projects. However I am unable to get the dynamic path at run time to keep it in one place..
For now I am using reflection to get the path of it from the calling project using GetCallingAssembly.

How can I can keep it under one project and not hard code the path and use it in the other two projects?

```
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
string actualPath = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("bin"));
string projectPath = new Uri(actualPath).LocalPath;
string fileToRead = projectPath + @"TestData.xlsx";
```

Comment: What are the paths of the three projects?

Comment: C:\Users\kevin.davis\source\repos\ExcelBranch\Project1                C:\Users\kevin.davis\source\repos\ExcelBranch\Project2              C:\Users\kevin.davis\source\repos\ExcelBranch\Project3

Comment: `Path.Combine(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase, @"..\Project2")` etc

Comment: how to mention the file to read "TestData.xlsx"

Comment: `Path.Combine` it in.

Comment: it still gets from the calling dll. I put the path like this                                                 
 string path = Path.Combine(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase, @"..\Project2\TestData.xlsx");//System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;                                                                                                                                               //System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;

Comment: path shows the file should be in Project1 since I am calling from it..